# How to handle SQLiteException Exception while fetching all the available tables in database?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I am showing the all available tables from my database in to list view.
But if there are no any tables there then it will give the numm pointer Exception.
The code is like below:

```
public ArrayList<Object> showAllTable()
```

{
      ArrayList tableList = new ArrayList();

```
  String SQL_GET_ALL_TABLES = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'";
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SQL_GET_ALL_TABLES, null);


  //////////////////

  if (cursor.moveToLast()) 
  {    

      do 
      {       
          if(cursor.getString(0).equals("android_metadata"))
          {
              //System.out.println("Get Metadata");
              continue;
          }
          else
          {
              tableList.add(cursor.getString(0));
          }
      }
      while (cursor.moveToPrevious());
  }
  ///////////////////////
  cursor.close();

  return tableList;
  }
```

Please help me in this
And the Exception i got is like:

```
09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error: create table null (_id integer primary key, isbn text not null,title text not null,word text not null,sound text not null,publisher text not null);
09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1727)
09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574):     at com.quiz.spellingquiz.DBAdapter$DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DBAdapter.java:68)
09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574):     at com.quiz.spellingquiz.DBAdapter.open(DBAdapter.java:88)
09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574):     at com.quiz.spellingquiz.MenuPage$2.onClick(MenuPage.java:51)
09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

So, give me solution how to resolve it. . .  Thanks.

The Line at 68 is:

```
 private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        //db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
```

// below line is 68
            db.execSQL("create table "+DATABASE_TABLE+" (_id integer primary key, "
                    + "isbn text not null," 
                    + "title text not null,"
                    + "word text not null,"
                    + "sound text not null,"
                    + "publisher text not null);");
        }

```
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version "+oldVersion+" to "+newVersion+", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste code written in DBAdapter.java

Comment: there are more code in DBAdapter.java. Which code you want to see ?

Comment: specially around line 68

Comment: that means you are not assigned(initialized) any value to the variable "DATABASE_TABLE".you have to initialize the value before using it.In ur case that is problem. Check whether DATABASE_TABLE is initialized or not.

Comment: Yes, there are no any table created. But at that time i want to display the toast message. So how to set that condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your DATABASE_TABLE variable is null and probably that is why you are getting null pointer exception.

based on this error

09-09 09:57:25.873: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(574): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error: create table null (_id integer primary key, isbn text not null,title text not null,word text not null,sound text not null,publisher text not null);

Comment: Ok . Thanks. But the Problem is while i am creating the db it will autometicaly create the table while ther is no any table name. So i have set the condition there. And it works great. Thanks for the Support.

Answer (score 1):

see the example code.

```
public class DBAdapter 
{          
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String USERDETAILS=
    "create table userdetails(usersno integer primary key autoincrement,userid text not null ,username text not null,password text not null,photo BLOB,visibility text not null);";
private final Context context; 

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        db.execSQL(USERDETAILS);

    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
    int newVersion) 
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}    

public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() 
{
    DBHelper.close();
}
}
```

Comment: what is this USERDETAILS in your syntex ?

Comment: USERDETAILS is the sql statement to create the table

Comment: Ok . Thanks. But the Problem is while i am creating the db it will autometicaly create the table while ther is no any table name. So i have set the condition there. And it works great. Thanks for the Support.